# When should I observe Javascript events on window vs. document vs. document.body?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm using prototype.js for my web app, and I have everything running on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.  I am now working on IE8 compatibility.

As I've been debugging in IE, I've noticed that there are Javascript events for which I have previously set an observer on the window, e.g.

```
Event.observe(window, eventType, function () {...});
```

(where `eventType` might be `"dom:loaded"`, `"keypress"`, etc.) and it works just fine in Chrome/Safari/Firefox.  However, in IE the observer never fires.

In at least some cases I could get this to work on IE by instead placing the observer on something other than `window`, e.g.  `document` (in the case of `"dom:loaded"`) or `document.body` (in the case of `"keypress"`).  However, this is all trial-and-error.

Is there some more systematic way to determine where to place these observers such that the results will be cross-browser compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various browsers' object documentation (e.g. [`window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535873(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN, [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document#Event_handlers) on MDC) define which events are supported on the object. You could start there.

Comment: The docs don't do a particularly good job of explaining this.

Comment: This does seem like a good place to look, but as far as I can tell the MSDN aren't comprehensive.  For example, one can register an `onresize` event on the `window`, but I don't actually see it listed there.

Comment: That's because `onresize` is exposed by `window.prototype` on IE. It's in the doc.

Comment: Ah-ha!  [`window.prototype`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347144.aspx) Thanks Alsciende.

Answer (score 36):

(This is not a super-comprehensive answer, but it seems to work out empirically -- so hopefully these rules of thumb will be helpful to others.)

- In general, register events on `document`, not `window`.  Webkit and mozilla browsers seem to be happy with either, but IE doesn't respond to most events registered on the window, so you need to use `document` to work with IE
- Exception: `resize`, and events related to loading, unloading, and opening/closing should all be set on the window.
- Exception to the first exception: `dom:loaded` must be set on `document` in IE.
- Another exception: When detecting keystrokes under Mozilla with find-as-you-type enabled, set your key event observers on the `window`, not the `document`.  If you do the latter, the find-as-you-type seems to block the event.

Comment: Are there any update on this question by any chance?

Comment: Note that in Firefox Quantum, if you enable the "Search for text when you start typing" option, `window.addEventListener('keyup', handler)` will also NOT work.