# Stenciljs custom event not responding via @Listen

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, stenciljs

I am trying to understand the flow of the custom event emitter. I have the rolling code where the mouse events work but not the custom events.  Tracing it through dev tools, it is emitting but not getting picked up by the listener.

The top-level component is here:

```
import { Component, Prop, Listen, State, Event, EventEmitter } from "@stencil/core"

@Component ({
    tag: "control-comp"
})
export class  SmsComp1 {
    @Prop() compTitle:string;
    @State() stateData: object = {name: "Fred"};

    @Event() stateChanged: EventEmitter;

    @Listen('inBox')
    inBoxHandler(ev) {
        console.log('In box', ev);
        this.stateData["name"] = ev.name;
        console.log('Emitting')
        this.stateChanged.emit(this.stateData);   
    }

    render () {
        let index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.compTitle}</h1>
                {index.map( (i) => {
                    return <my-component first={i.toString()} last="Don't call me a framework" width={i*40} height={i*40}></my-component>
                })} 
                <my-component first={this.stateData["name"]} last="'Don't call me a framework' JS"></my-component>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The component is here:

```
import { Component, Prop, Listen, State, Event, EventEmitter } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {

  @Prop() first: string;
  @Prop() last: string;
  @Prop() width: number = 120;
  @Prop() height: number = 100;
  @State() colour: string = 'red';

  @Event() inBox: EventEmitter;

  @Listen('mouseover') 
  clickHandler() {
    this.colour = 'white';
    this.inBox.emit({action: 'IN_BOX',
                    name: this.first+' '+this.last})
  }

  @Listen('mouseout')
  mouseOutHandler() {
    this.colour = 'red';
  }

  @Listen('stateChanged')
  stateChangedHandler(state) {
    console.log('Received', state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <svg width={this.width+10} height={this.height+10}>
          <rect width={this.width} height={this.height} fill='green'></rect>
          <circle cx={this.width/2} cy={this.height/2} r={this.width*0.1} fill={this.colour}></circle>
          <text fill='white' x='10' y='10'>{this.first+' '+this.last}</text>
        </svg>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally the index.html is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
  <title>Stencil Component Starter</title>
  <script src="/build/mycomponent.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <control-comp compTitle="Stencil Example"></control-comp>
  <my-component first="My Dead" last='Component' width=100 height=120></my-component>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you suggest why the stateChanged event is not being noticed by `my-component`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stencil events, like other `CustomEvent`s only bubble *up* a component tree, not down.

Since `my-component` is a child of `control-comp`, the parent's `stateChanged` event can't seen by `control-comp`.

You'll want to find another approach to have a parent communicate to a child component. The "standard" way to do this is to set a `@Prop` and maybe a `@Watch` on the child, and update the prop in the parent's `render()` function.

Or, you could use a more robust approach like [stencil-redux](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-redux) or [stencil-state-tunnel](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-state-tunnel).

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's to late but you can use the options for `@Listen`

```
export interface ListenOptions {
  target?: 'parent' | 'body' | 'document' | 'window';
  capture?: boolean;
  passive?: boolean;
}
```

(Source: https://stenciljs.com/docs/events#listen-s-options)

If you attach the Listener to `document` you will get the expected event

```
@Listen('inBox', { target: 'document' })
...
```

Comment: Worth noting this article that specifically recommends targeting document/window as an approach to event listening: https://gomakethings.com/why-event-delegation-is-a-better-way-to-listen-for-events-in-vanilla-js/

And you're probably better off opting for "document" most of the time, especially with your own custom events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2671217